# QSqlDatabase doesn't see a table

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I've created a database which definitely exists in the project directory, I can open it using DBBrowser and  Ubuntu terminal. They both show that the database contains 'movies' table, but my code in c++ says that such table wasn't found

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("TestDatabase.db");

if(!db.open())
{
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
    qFatal("Failed to connect");
}

qDebug("Connected");

QSqlQuery query(db);


if(!query.exec("INSERT INTO movies (TITLE,RELEASE,STUDIO,DIRECTOR) VALUES ('Batman v Superman' , 2016 , 'WB', 'ZackSnyder');"))
{
    qDebug() << query.lastError();
}
else {
    qDebug("INSERTED!");
}
```

Output

```
Connected
QSqlError("1", "Unable to execute statement", "no such table: movies")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have your database in the same folder as your source code, but when you run and compile the application it'll be in a release / debug folder where the database obviously doesn't exist.

Now what happens is that Qt creates the database when it doesn't exist therefore you get the `Connected` message.

Specify the full path and database name once to try it. It should perform as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it! Database file is being creating in the debug folder.

Comment: It's always the little things that get you.

Comment: I fell for it too, so I know :)

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code (and adjusted the path) and ran it on database created like

`sqlite3 /tmp/TestDatabase.db
SQLite version 3.14.0 2016-07-26 15:17:14
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table movies(TITLE text,RELEASE text,STUDIO text,DIRECTOR text);
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE movies(TITLE text,RELEASE text,STUDIO text,DIRECTOR text);`

and it works as expected so it probably comes to how are you testing this
are you sure you are running your binary from the same place where database is located? Are you maybe using .qrc for deployment?